# Android SDK implementing personalized Google Voice Search

Tags: android, speech-recognition

Google Voice Search recently came out with the new feature of personalized voice profiles, in which the Voice Search will learn your voice and become more accurate overtime. Is this feature only found in Google's Voice Search app? Or is it part of Google's Speech Input API, in which I can implement in my own voice app with the RecognizerIntent or SpeechRecognizer class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API is publicly documented, so it's easy to find out, see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/package-summary.html). What you describe is not in the API (as of Android v4.1).